# How to add a module function to the window object with require.js?

Tags: javascript, requirejs

In my current project I am working with [krpano](http://krpano.com/), a multi resolution panorama image viewer for the browser. You can add clickable hotspots on a panorama and define a function, that is executed, when the hotspot is clicked.

The method I want to be executed is inside a require.js module, but the krpano library only calls methods, that are attached to the global window object.

**How can I add my method from a module to the window object, so that I still have access to all of my other dependent modules?**

My application consists of plenty modules with dependencies.

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're not giving much details but two ways to do it come to mind. What is most appropriate really depends on the specifics of your application.

1. This is what I'd prefer to do if I had to leak a function from a module because it does not make the module *itself* leak the function. If this module is reusable at all, then I could use it in another project where I don't have to leak anything. I'd write my module like any other AMD module and then, I'd have glue code pull out what I need to leak. The module (in a `mod.js` file):

   ```
   define(["a", "b"], function (a, b) {
       return { 
           foo: function () {},
           bar: function () {}
       };
   });
   ```

   The glue code:

   ```
   require(["mod"], function (mod) {
       window.foo = mod.foo; // Leak the function I need for **this** project.
   });
   ```
2. Make the module itself leak a function. This makes the module inherently leaky and harms reuse but sometimes some modules are so tied to the specific project they are created for that reuse is not going to happen, so...

   ```
   define(["a", "b"], function (a, b) {
       function foo () {}
       window.foo = foo;
       return { 
           foo: foo,
           bar: function () {}
       }
   });
   ```

Comment: Thank you for this detailed answer. The second approach came already to my mind, but I wanted to know, whether there is a better one. In the end I took the second and it works as I want it. You are absolutely right by saying, that it is for modules, that do not need this high reusability. Thanks again!